# How would I get the value of an internal variable within Vagrant?

Tags: ruby, vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualbox

Is it possible to read machine state for a Vagrant managed VM into a local variable within the context of a `Vagrantfile`? That is to say, once Vagrant has assigned a variable for the machine, e.g. the MAC address or even the name, is it possible to access and read those values from within a block inside a `Vagrantfile`?

For instance, If I have a `Vagrantfile` that provisions a VM using VirtualBox that VM will be assigned a generated name unless I explicitly assign it, as represented in the logging that Vagrant emits, e.g.:

> ==> default: Setting the name of the VM: myvm-vm_1458159771938_18157

I am asking in part because of academic curiousity (because I haven't discovered how on my own) and also because I ran into a scenario where being able to read the value of an internal variable for a machine, either the name or the mac address could have been useful.

I have tried directly accessing the configuration components, like `config.vm.base_mac` etc. but most of them are all `#<Object:0x0...>` instances that appear to have no practical value.

Comment: Why do you need to use them inside the vagrantfile? If you need to network, you can set the hostname and name of the box explicitly in the vagrantfile. For academic purposes, you could read whatever you wanted via the provisioning script, and since a vagrantfile is really just Ruby you could do whatever you want in Ruby inside the vagrantfile - am I missing something?

Comment: @brian-morton As noted above, this is somewhat academic at this point. Colleagues and I were running into an issue where we had to always supply unique hostnames for newly provisioned VMs to a Puppet Master because it would reject them otherwise. Eventually, I found a configuration setting that allowed the Puppet Master to accept non-unique hostnames, but before that I was looking for a way to assign a unique, generated, hostname. My first thought was to access something like the MAC address or another value from within Vagrant.

Comment: You could use Ruby's `SecureRandom` to get a UUID to use that as the hostname - `p SecureRandom.hex(10)` for example.

Comment: @BrianMorton: Thanks for the suggestion!